# Xcode 14.3 Showing Multiple commands produce on IOS flavoring in flutter

Tags: flutter

I am trying to implement flavoring on the ISO side I have two GoogleServive-info.plist files for both dev and prod. when I try to archive its shows an error listed below.
[image]

Comment: how are you copying the info.plist to the right path? it seems that your configuration is duplicated but it would be great if you can add details on how you implemented the flavors on xcode